# Running a Java Applet in Current Browsers?

Tags: java, html, applet

I have created a Java applet as part of a request from a client for a web-based program, and while I've gotten it embedded, Chrome has disabled support, you need to bypass various security protocols in both Internet Explorer and Firefox, and Edge doesn't have support for java in the first place. My question is, is there some sort of way we can run this program through a wrapper or an alternative way of getting it on the web without re-writing the entire program in a different language? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, as you're seeing, applets are dead.  Your best option is to use [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) and convert your applet into an application.  That really isn't too bad to do but it will require some work.

Basically the server sends a JNLP file that runs an application.  The application (i.e. your Java application) can be downloaded from a remote server so that you don't have to have pre-installed anything except for Java on the client machine.

Comment: *"Your best option is to use Java Web Start"* Agreed. Unless it needs to interact directly with the web pages the user is looking at. *"..and convert your applet into an application."* Not necessarily required. JWS could launch applets free floating on the desktop ever since its introduction.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into this.